# Pushing TimeClock Data from Mobile Phone to Quickbooks

Tags: c#, vb.net, quickbooks

I need to find a solution or develop one for allowing employees to enter their "hours worked" at the end of the day and then easily and quickly "pushing" that data to Quickbooks Pro 2010.

I'm trying to formulate, in my mind, how to build this type of solution. With my  understanding of QuickBooks integration I think it will look like the following:

```
Quickbooks Software on PC  
             |  
             |  
Custom App "Linking" Online DataStore to QB (on same PC as above)
             |  
             |  
Online Data Store Such as MS SQL Server, MySQL, or CSV Files  
             |  
             |  
Website or Web Service Used to Receive Data From Blackberry Phones  
             |  
             |  
App on Blackberry Phone to Enter and "Push" Data To Data Store in the Cloud
```

Do you see any flaws in this design? Any ideas how to improve on it or simplify it?

Remember, the application on the PC will likely be on a consumer or small business network that doesn't even have static IP.

On a separate note, as near as I can tell nothing yet exists that will do what I'm looking for. The apps I have looked at require you to import iif files into your phone (specifically ReportAway). During an initial test of the app, the import failed to import anything but did not produce any error messages. It's unclear to me how the data gets input from the BlackBerry app to QuickBooks but it appears to simply be CSV files. If someone does know of an existing app for this I'd appreciate knowing about it. However, we may still opt to program our own anyway.

Comment: Side note in addition to my post below- contact me, we might be interested in developing this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with what you proposed. I have a few further suggestions:

- Instead of building a custom app that sits alongside QuickBooks, why not re-use something that's already built? For instance, the [QuickBooks Web Connector](http://marketplace.intuit.com/webconnector/) or (if you're building a SaaS service) the Sync Manager via the [Intuit Partner Platform](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/)? Both of those are specifically designed to enable web/remote applications to communicate with QuickBooks. There are C# examples of doing almost exactly what you're talking about included in the QuickBooks SDK, and [open source QuickBooks libraries](https://code.intuit.com/sf/projects/ipp_dev_kits) for doing what you're asking.
- Why would you ever want to use CSV files for storing data? Do yourself a favor, and use a database.
- You could easily make the phone end of things available via more than once interface- build a web interface for iPhones/web browsers, and an app for Blackberry if you want. Once you have the infrastructure, the actual interface/view should be trivial to implement.
- Have you looked at the available [Workplace.Intuit.com apps for time tracking](http://workplace.intuit.com/Category/time-tracking) yet?

Comment: I did look at the QB Web Connector. It is definitely an option but it appeared to me to relieve only a very small percentage of the necessary programming as you still have to program all of your own QBXML classes. This web connector doesn't provide any "wrappers" for commonly used tasks.

Comment: Also, I've looked extensively for what apps are available for this and none of them satisfy the need, as near as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

are you wanting to build your own app? Your best option is the build your phone app that makes a call to a web service hosted somewhere on the network where QB is hosted, the service can use the QB API to put the data where you need it. Or simply create a website that they can browse to that will make the call to the API, then you dont even need to bother with a phone app.

Phone/Website > Web Service > QB/SQL

Comment: I'm a little worried that users entering their time on a BlackBerry browser could be too frustrating. It would certainly be a good way of simplifying the design.

Comment: I don't use blackberry so I have no idea but IMO a web page would be best option. Faster development, you can make the page very simple and you don't have to worry about developing a black berry app, trying to get it integrated with the network, etc.

Comment: The web browser on a BlackBerry is pretty clumsy compared to the iPhone or Android. I think it could possibly work but I expect most people would get frustrated pretty quickly with it.

Comment: how complex are you thinking? I'm thinking it can handle a textbox or two and a button. If you still dont want to do a web page, by all means do an app. The end result is the same, make a call to a web service.

Comment: This solution likely won't work- most people don't have their QuickBooks company hosted on the same server as their website, and there's no reliable way to directly enable remote access to a QuickBooks company file over the network (it's *not* like an always-on SQL database).

Comment: @Keith, yes there is. QB API is a web service. No one said to have it on the same serer as QB (which some companies actually DO do this). Make a call to the QB API (web service which requires setting up SSL and X509 certs) from your website (doesn't have to be same server)

Comment: When you install QB and the SDK you can also setup a web service to access the QB API instead of direct DLL references.

Comment: Are you talking about RDS? RDS is no where near reliable enough to be used in an environment like this. The only other QuickBooks desktop API there is are wrappers around QuickBooks' COM interfaces, or IDS/IPP (which I mentioned). The problem with those is that if you're in single-user mode in QuickBooks, or if you're running QuickBooks updates, it *won't let you connect* to QuickBooks- a significant problem if you're banking on being able to always connect to QuickBooks. Or am I misunderstanding you? Can you link to whatever "QB API" you're talking about?

Comment: Um, I agree that this solution does appear to me to require QB and the web service to run on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved exactly this problem in the past, in a manner very similar to as described by DustinDavis.  In my case, I simply connect the smartphone client app to the php app server.  App server stores the data immediately.  In a separate scheduled process, app server refreshes and pushes data to QuickBooks server every 15 minutes or every 30 minutes as configured.  I can provide more details if you are interested.